# what to do about different resolution in android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I designed my layout on emulator with resolution 1920*1080 and all thing were good but now I install on my device with resolution 1280*720 and it's not good and all thing (ImageView and TextView) seems longer than 1920*1080 resolution.although I use from `dp` for ImageView and `sp` for TextView but they are longer.I must design layout for this resolution or several resolution? I want to be same in different.what should i do?

Comment: Wrap your view in a ScrollView then it will keep the aspect ratio but on a smaller screen, you will have to scroll the view.

Comment: If your app will run in different devices I'd recommend using a constraint layout with properly set barriers and guidelines over using the library suggested below. https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this line in your `build.gradle` (Module: app) in `dependencies`:

```
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
```

And then express your dimension in xml file with:

```
"@dimen/_[number]sdp"
```

For example, a `TextView` will become so:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_sample"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_300sdp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_58sdp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />
```

It won't be precise to the millimeter, but it's more precise than using just `dp` and `sp`.

**Important:** Don't forget to "sync now" the gradle when you add lines in `.gradle` files

Library source: https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Comment: It's so bigger again.see this link : https://ibb.co/VDQjXXb .i think i must design layout for each resolution.yes?

Comment: If you want a millimeter-precise layout, yes; otherwise, this is the best way to handle different screen densities without designing dozens of layouts